# How do I execute javascript programs from the Linux shell?

Tags: javascript, linux, shell, kernel, rhino

I would like to execute my javascript programs with the [Rhino shell](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Rhino_Shell) without making the first line #!/bin/sh. '#' isn't a comment character in javascript. I also don't want to have to have a .js extension.

Is this possible? I remember reading something a long while about a method of making java programs to run without an explicit interpreter. Google has not been forthcoming, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the kernel-module `binfmt_misc` for this. I don't have a JS interpreter installed, but I guess the magic would be something like this for Rhino:

```
# If it's not included in your kernel
sudo modprobe binfmt_misc
sudo mount binfmt_misc -t binfmt_misc /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc

# Register the .js extension as being run by Rhino
echo ':JSScript:E::js::/path/to/rhino:' > /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register
```

This assumes that your scripts are happy to be run like:

```
 /path/to/rhino /path/to/your/script
```

If you need to pass any arguments to Rhino, then you'll need to set up a wrapper. Full documentation for `binfmt_misc` is [here](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/binfmt_misc.txt).

Comment: And don't forget to make the script executable.

Comment: Since I wanted to be able to name my scripts without the file extension, I also added:echo ':javascript:M:://!::/usr/bin/js:' > /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register

Answer (score 0):

Yes, simply call `rhino /path/to/your/js/file`

In case you don't have a program `rhino` in your path, replace it with `java org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main`